# Mimicking apply() with rank() of R in Python

Tags: python, r, dataframe, rank

I want to mimic the following code in R to Python:

```
# matrix with a rank that handles ties of values including zeros and NA
# matrix is a single row data frame
# matrix_res is an array or list in R
matrix_res = apply(matrix, 1, rank, ties.method = "average")
```

My attempt to doing this in Python is the following which works great except it didn't handle tied zero values, the zeroes should be rank the lowest:

```
  matrix.rank(method='first', na_option='bottom')
```

If I change any of the parameters of python rank, it will mess up with one tied value? How can I do this same rank R code above but in Python?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry not familiar with R so would you mind including a small sample input and desired output? Also is your matrix a `np.matrix`, `np.ndarray`, `pd.DataFrame`, or just plain ol python `list`?